# For $q$-analogues of a known curious identity

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-identities, q-analogs, q-identities

In 2002 I published the folllowing curious combinatorial identity:
$$(x+m+1)\sum_{i=0}^m(-1)^i\binom{x+y+i}{m-i}\binom{y+2i}i-\sum_{i=0}^m\binom{x+i}{m-i}(-4)^i=(x-m)\binom xm.$$
My original proof is based on double recursions. During 2002-2004, five other proofs of this identity appeared. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun%27s_curious_identity.

Many combinatorial identities have their $q$-analogues. However, up to now nobody has given a $q$-analogue of the curious identity mentioned above.

QUESTION: Are there any $q$-analogues of the above curious identity?

Any comments are welcome!

Comment: Is it a typo that the left-hand side of this identity involves $y$ and the right-hand side does not?

Comment: @Sam Hopkins  That's not a typo. The first sum can be shown to be independent of $y$.

Comment: Wow! Definitely earned the name "curious" then.